# Adding inbound rules to aws ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

What I really need to ask is that if multiple rules in a security group bound to an instance which accept traffic from port 22, 80 and 443 i.e ssh, http and https is the same thing as defining a single rule i.e custom-tcp which accepts traffic from port 0-60000. Will implementing the latter provision the same kind of access as the former?

In my system I'm trying to add rules to the default security group with node SDK/API and I thought just adding one rule to accept all kinds of traffic would be better than defining them separately but I'm not sure about that.

Image 1: Access with multiple rules on separate ports:

[image: Image 1: Access with multiple rules on separate ports]

Image 2: Access with a single rule for all ports:
[image: Image2: Access with a single rule for all ports]

Answer (score 2):

> Will implementing the latter provision the same kind of access as the former?

Sadly, they are **not equivalent**, though technically they will both allow `22, 80 and 443` ports.

The `0-60000` will allow incoming connections on **all ports**. This does not agree well with the security best practice of granting [least privileged](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#grant-least-privilege) permissions only.

In contrast, `22, 80 and 443` will allow only the **three ports**. Any access on other ports will be denied. If you don't need another ports, this option is better from the security perspective.